# Having issues with Memcached class?

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, memcached

I'm having trouble doing a `composer install` on a Symfony project I've cloned, and the error message is:

`PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Memcached' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\foo\vendor\doctrine\doctrine-cache-bundle\Tests\Functional\Fixtures\Memcached.php on line 5`

I've downloaded and installed Memcached as found [here](https://commaster.net/content/installing-memcached-windows), and I've put the extension file in my ext directory. I've also gone into my `php.ini` and written in the extension. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Memcached is the name of the cache process, you create objects from class 'Memcache'. From the page you link to...

```
$memcache = new Memcache;
$memcache->connect('localhost', 11211) or die ("Could not connect");
```

Comment: Glad to be able to help, can you mark the question as answered if your problem is solved.